# My folders are still locked (External Hard Drive)

Tags: permissions, external-hdd

I've been up and down this forum site trying to make this external drive I'v setup to have rw/rw/rw so no matter what computer I plug it in to I can access it. By access I mean use it as a git backup(push/pull), save documents to it and of course read from it. It works fine on my home computer but when I plug it in at work or to other computers the folders I've created on it are still locked. They show a lock symbol on it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdT5w.png)

I tried doing the following but it has failed in making my folders and all sub folders to be accessible from another work station even though it says everyone can "Create/Delete files".

```
gksudo nautilus
```

I've tried plugging in my external drive to another computer that I have root access to and I can add files as that way but I have to be root. I don't have root on my work computer so I have to find a way to setup this drive to be accessible. I've also plugged it into a computer I have root access and typed

```
sudo chmod 666 -R /media/shane/BlackBox
```

This still doesn't work. There are a few other commands I tried but I can't recall every single one of them. I've been stuck on this for 3 days now doing my research on here the best I can but have failed. I need some help.

Comment: Use my `pathlld` tool to diagnose. `git clone https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git`

Comment: `sudo chmod 666 -R /media/shane/BlackBox` does not alter the USER that owns it. Mind that directories NEED "7" so your command messed the permissions up big time,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to change the owner of the folders ?

by typing:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /your_folder
```

After that you can type in your terminal:

```
ls -l
```

or to go *your_folders->properties*

To see if there is any change concerning the owner of the folder, It should be the case.

---

To fix the errors by your chmod use

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644
```

to fix that.

Comment: chown ? chmod is for file permissions

Comment: chmod will changes the permission for all files in the folder but when you add the -R it also modify the directory (see the documentation) permission ;)

Comment: @lolo hope you do not mind the editing. Have an upvote ;-)

Comment: haha @Rinzwind why suggest when we can edit. better strategy

Comment: @lolo Thanks for the help as well to the others. This worked great except I noticed for my repositories I have on the external drive when I type the commands above to fix errors it says 

chmod: changing permissions of './Home/Projects/bla/bla/repo.git/objects/long hash code here' : Operation not permitted

Comment: Also would you be so kind to explain what the two "find . ..." commands above are doing? Not quite understanding the purpose of them.

Comment: Oh sorry I have not see your second question... So, the first command  find . -type d allows you to find in the current directory all directories and the second find command allows you to find all files. The xargs command allows you to apply the chmod command on the elements found by the find command. I you want more information about these two commands you can type in your terminal:  **man  find**